# How to use window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{}) on useEffect hooks

Tags: reactjs

I want to try console a message when window is fully loaded, I try for this code :

```
  function tes(){
    console.log('Hello World')
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('load', tes)
    })
  }, [])
```

How to properly using it in useEffect hooks ?

Comment: You don't need the `})` after `window.addEventListener('load', tes)` since you close the arrow function and useEffect later on

Comment: You don't add a listener for 'load' event in useEffect because if useEffect is called, it means window is already loaded. Unless you are using SSR which you need to test typeof window !== 'undefined'